Does every variable need to be statistically significant in a regression model?
I recently fit a regression model (ARIMAX) in which some variables (3) were statistically significant and some were not (1). I removed the statistically insignificant variables and refit the model, now all variables are statistically significant (i.e. new model has 3 variables, old model has 4 variables).
However, this new model (where all variables are statistically significant) is performing worse than the old model (where not all variables are statistically significant). That is, the new model has worse forecasting error compared to the old model.
Is this common practice in statistics? Is it more advisable to pick a model with poorer performance provided all variables are statistical significant or is it better to pick the model with better performance even though not all variables are statistically significant.
I am aware of concepts such as overfitting and cross validation. I trained both models on all available data except the last 6 months of data. I also made both models predict the last 6 months of available data and compared predicted values to the actual values. I still got better results with the old model (i.e. the model where not all variables were statistically significant).
Is it ok go to with the better performing model even though not all variables are statistically significant?


Does every variable need to statistically significant in a regression model?

As I explain here, the answer is "No".

Is it more advisable to pick a model with poorer performance provided all variables are statistical significant or is it better to pick the model with better performance even though not all variables are statistically significant.

Statistical significance of all variables in the model is a poor criterion for model selection.  Generally, you should decide what the purpose of your model is before collecting data, and decide how you will determine if one model is better than another.
To quote my other answer...

If you are only interested in predicting [the outcome], then statistical hypothesis tests really aren't your main concern. Instead, you should be externally validating your model via a validation/test procedure on unseen data.
If, instead, you are interested in examining which factors [drive variability in the outcome], then there is no need to remove variables which fail to reject the null [...] Presumably, you included a variable in your model because you thought (from past experience or expert opinion) that it played an important part in [the outcome]. That the variable failed to reject the null doesn't make your model a bad one, it just means that your sample didn't detect an effect of that variable. That's perfectly ok.


thanks! so to recap: if your goal is prediction, the primary importance is to make sure the model is predicting well using cross validation?

When I see “non-significant” (a bullshit term if there ever was one) variables in a model I have much more confidence in the analyst, knowing they are not double-dipping and creating falsely narrow confidence intervals and p-values that are too small by ignoring model uncertainty.

Hmm while I agree mostly, I think the answer misses out that there are a lot of filter methods looking at pvalues to drop variables https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest people do this... Not saying it was good though ...

@Ggjj11 The filtering methods you mention are not very good methods.  My intent is to point OP to more justifiable approaches and away from poor approaches -- not to give OP a tour of methods good and bad.

@user439249  If your goal is prediction, then performance of the model on unseen data is the way to determine of a model is better than some other model. Cross validation is one approach to doing this, but ultimately you will need some additional data the model has not seen in order to say definitively if the model can predict the phenomenon.

The answer provided by Demetri already provides a sufficient answer here (+1). If your model's intent is to predict, then the $p$-values matter a lot less than the model's ability to guess on future outcomes. As he mentioned, tools like cross-validation go a long way to determining whether or not your model is really good at prediction. To a degree, other inferential data like your standard errors and the magnitude of the associations are probably much better barometers of your model's ability to predict anyway.
If the goal is theory testing (the major part of my answer here), then adding or removing variables based on $p$ values is a poor practice and entirely misses the objective of the analysis. Here I will use a practical example from my own field to perhaps demonstrate why variable selection based on $p$ values is a bad idea.
Suppose we are interested in two skills which predict reading. The first skill is phonological awareness (PA), or the ability to recognize the sound rules in a word (e.g. knowing that "fight" and "might" rhyme). The second is morphological awareness (MA), which is the ability to recognize the morphological constructions of a word (e.g. "eyeball" is separately made up of the words "eye" and "ball"). It may be the case that in the population, the relationship between reading and these two cognitive skills is:
$$
\text{Reading} = 1 + (2 \times \text{PA}) + (.0001 \times \text{MA}) + \epsilon
$$
I'm writing these in a rush, so these wouldn't reflect their actual values in my field. We can anyway easily see that PA has a strong relationship with reading, whereas MA has a poor relationship. But perhaps our inference based on past research is that these predictors should have an equally strong relationship, perhaps something like:
$$
\text{Reading} = 1 + (2 \times \text{PA}) + (2 \times \text{MA}) + \epsilon
$$
It may be the case that we find some data to test how important each association is. We can simulate the true population values in R and see what the regression tells us:
#### Simulate ####
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1000
pa <- rnorm(n)
ma <- rnorm(n)
read <- 1 + 2*pa + (.0001 * ma) + rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(pa,ma,read)
pairs(df)

#### Fit ####
fit <- lm(read ~ pa + ma)
summary(fit)

The model predictably shows that $X_1$ has a strong association and $X_2$ doesnt:
Call:
lm(formula = read ~ pa + ma)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.13161 -0.71957  0.03478  0.70215  3.05316 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.02996    0.03204  32.150   <2e-16 ***
pa           2.01770    0.03217  62.712   <2e-16 ***
ma          -0.03680    0.03270  -1.125    0.261    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.013 on 997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.798, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7976 
F-statistic:  1969 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Well we already know that this is how it should look (which is never the case in reality). Our model is nudging us to answer the question of how important each variable is. You can see that it does pretty good at capturing the intercept and the slope for PA while getting it a bit wrong with the negative coefficient for MA, but regardless showing that it is quite weak (and so unsurprisingly the $p$ values are not statistically significant even with $n=1000$ observations). That is the entire point of a regression. We are sampling from the population and trying to use that sample to guess what the population is. By tossing out the variables we cared about, we destroy our inference about the variables in question, in essence throwing our our assumptions that each slope $\beta = 2$ (though in a situation like this, its probably better to go full Bayesian anyway given we have prior information about what the effect should be, but that is a separate point).
All of this is particularly germane to practical implications of the model. If one skill happens to be great at predicting reading while the other doesn't, then naturally our model with a poorly predictive cognitive skill is extremely important for informing educators to not waste their time and resources on this issue. How can others know this if you don't include it in your model? And yet this seems to happen more commonly than one would think.
